# Where I can propose suggestions for Ubuntu?

Tags: launchpad, canonical

I know launchpad (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs) is where you can post bugs both against the operating system and software that it includes, but is that place to propose improvements to feedback mode?

Unfortunately there is no native functionality of Ubuntu where one can submit feedback but if there are many things I would like to comment and discuss (all with clear arguments and good way), but where do I do this?

For example in most google products have a button or menu where you can give your feedback which is not necessarily a bug but also suggestions for potential improvements in both web services and the app development tools.

Where can I make this kind of suggestion?

Comment: edwinksl is right, feature requests almost always goes to bugtrackers. Additionally I'd mention that you need to find bugtracker specifically of the software that you want to make a feature request to. E.g. most KDE apps belongs to `https://bugs.kde.org`. The confusing thing is that you can report them to launchpad too, but in the case of KDE apps your report would rather get to Ubuntu packagers, than the actual developers of those. You can easily find the needed bugtracker by keywords "appNameYouReInterestedIn report bug".

Comment: @Hi-Angel You raised a good point about packages not using the bug tracker in Launchpad. Please feel free to write an answer to address that scenario.

Comment: @edwinksl I think it's pretty little for a full answer, the more that most peoples likely to read only the accepted and highly upvoted answer, which is yours here :) But feel free to add it to your answer if you feel it's valuable enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/99338, I think you still create a bug report in Launchpad but make it explicit that you are really doing a feature request and your "bug report" will probably be tagged appropriately by the package maintainers.